# Set table in a value in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a key which has fields and values. All the fields have string values.
One of these fields I want it to be a table or set or list (meaning holding multiple values). This field is called *zonetable*
I only know how to use hset but as far as I know it cannot do what I want. I would like to do something like that

> hmset L0001:ad65ed38-66b0-46b4-955c-9ff4304e5c1a field1 blabla field2 blibli zonetable [1,2,3,4]

```
Key : L0001:ad65ed38-66b0-46b4-955c-9ff4304e5c1a
field1: "string value"
field2: "string value"
zonetable: [1,2,3,4]   ---- the table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make use of Json. use json serialize your table (list or something) into a json string, then use hset to save it into your redis.

When you want to retrieve it, first get it from redis and then deserialize it from json to list.

If you use python, you can do it like this:

```
 table = json.dumps(zonetable)
 redis.hset(Key, 'zonetable', table)
```

when you want to retrieve it :

```
table = redis.hget(Key, 'zonetable')
zonetable = json.loads(table)
```

As you say, you use the native command, you can also do this.

first, convert your zonetable to json string using python interpreter

```
>>> import json
>>> table = [1,2,3,4]
>>> json.dumps(table)
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

then use this in redis-cli

```
hmset L0001:ad65ed38-66b0-46b4-955c-9ff4304e5c1a field1 blabla field2 blibli zonetable '[1,2,3,4]'
```

Yes, one more thing I want to say, if you know the [rule of how to convert object to json](http://www.json.org/), you could do it by yourself.